# Closing Client Side Socket Without killing process

Tags: c++, c, network-programming

when i use `close(sock_fd);`

the socket hang in `CLOSE_WAIT` state.

*Is there any way out to close the socket completely.*

Comment: Maybe you can share code related to this. Please make sure it's a [mre].

Comment: Have you called `shutdown(sock_fd, SD_BOTH);` (Windows) or `shutdown(sock_fd, SHUT_RDWR);` (Linux) before closing?

Comment: What problem is the `CLOSE_WAIT` socket creating?